# Class is not exposing in WCF Services (XML)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(TemplateField))]

[XmlInclude(typeof(Template))]
public class Template
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Index("Uq_name", IsUnique = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty(Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull)]
    public virtual List<TemplateField> TemplatesFields { get; set; }
}
```

//Note: My WCF services not exposing the particular class in XML. I tried to    googling but not able to fix the issue. I am facing this issue only for this class only. My other class in WCF service(XML) working fine.

```
Like:
    <xs:complexType name="UserTemplate">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ContractID" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FieldLabelName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FieldDataType" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="StepNumber" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding
[DataContract] to
public class Template

Comment: @Dot_NETPro in the exemple above there is the DataContract in the Template class.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `[DataContract]` to your Template class.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Template))]
[DataContract]
public class Template
{
}
```

In your ServiceContract interface add one single operation related to Template which will make Template visible to your client application.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
[OperationContract]
List<Template> GetTemplates();
}
```

**Note:** If no operation contract exist for user defined classes, its definition won't     emit in proxy class generated using Svcutil.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your property not as virtual:

```
public List<TemplateField> TemplatesField
```

Are your TemplateField class contained in **System.Web.UI.WebControls** namespace?

If so, it will not be serialized, since it doesn't has DataContract attribute. If is class you've created, check if it's also has the DataContract attribute.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, My TemplateField Class already have DataContract attritube.